# glDrawElements() Returning GL_INVALID_ENUM in Invalid Circumstances

Tags: c++, opengl

All the method below `draw_data` does is draw a square with two triangles. Hence the hard coded values. The square renders just fine, however, I get spammed with

> vertex_renderer::draw_vertex_data()GL ERROR: Invalid enum.

from my code. Am I doing something wrong?

My rendering method is as follows:

```
bool draw_data(const GLsizei start_index = 0, GLsizei index_count = 0) {
  if (!vbo_id_ || start_index + index_count > index_count_) {
    return false;
  }

  if (index_count == 0) {
    index_count = index_count_;
  }

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  return !gl_errors::what_errors("vertex_renderer::draw_vertex_data()");
}
```

gl_errors::what_errors is defined as follows:

```
class gl_errors
{
public:
  static bool what_errors(const char * const prefix) {
    GLenum errorCode;
    bool is_error = false;

    while ((errorCode = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      switch (errorCode) {
      case(GL_INVALID_ENUM): {
        std::cout << prefix << "GL ERROR: Invalid enum." << std::endl;
        is_error = true;
      }
        break;
      case(GL_INVALID_VALUE): {
        std::cout << prefix << "GL ERROR: Invalid value." << std::endl;
        is_error = true;
      }
        break;
      case(GL_INVALID_OPERATION): {
        std::cout << prefix << "GL ERROR: Invalid operation." << std::endl;
        is_error = true;
      }
        break;
      case(GL_STACK_OVERFLOW): {
        std::cout << prefix << "GL ERROR: Stack overflow." << std::endl;
        is_error = true;
      }
        break;
      case(GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW): {
        std::cout << prefix << "GL ERROR: Stack underflow." << std::endl;
        is_error = true;
      }
        break;
      case(GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY): {
        std::cout << prefix << "GL ERROR: Out of memory." << std::endl;
        is_error = true;
      }
        break;
      }
    }
    return is_error;
  }
};
```

**UPDATE**

```
GLsizei stride = sizeof(verticies_t);
pos_id_ = basic_shader_.get_attribute("position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_id_);
glVertexAttribPointer(pos_id_, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0);
gl_extensions::gl_errors::what_errors("1");
```

This is the culprit, however I don't see why this is causing the problem. GL_FLOAT is a valid enum.

Comment: Are there errors prior to the call to `glDrawElements`?

Comment: There are and that is a good point let me double check to make sure i am checking for errors after each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glDrawElements()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) has just one condition under in which it returns `GL_INVALID_ENUM`:

> GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if mode is not an accepted value.

This should make you suspicious about other calls into the API since your `glDrawElements()` call has a valid mode. Add more check to calls made before and see if you track down your problem.

Comment: Good point, but for those on OpenGL ES2: beware! INVALID_ENUM is also triggered if you use integer indices instead of byte or shorts. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml